# How to enable NFC Reader depending on Fragments of same Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, nfc

I have Activity1 with 2 different Fragments (A, B). How do I disable NFC tags reader when Fragment B is visible and enable it when A is visible?

I thought in using `enableForegroundDispatch()` and `disableForegroundDispatch()` on the Activity when B is attached by calling `enableForegroundDispatch` inside `Activity1.onAttachFragments()` and `disableForegroundDispatch` inside `Activity1.onBackPressed` but I guess is not going to work because the activity is always visible in foreground then it'll always receive the tag intent...

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered this question, I will share my own solution which seems to work for me, even though the code is not "elegant" at all. First of all, I added a simple Boolean `isNfcActive` in my MainActivity, and changed it in my ReaderFragment as shown below:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val activity = activity as MainActivity
    activity.isNfcActive = true
}
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    val activity = activity as MainActivity
    activity.isNfcActive = false
}
```

Now everytime I get a new intent from NFC card, I check if reading is active. This way in every fragment except reader phone will vibrate, but only in your desired fragment this intent will be processed:

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        if (intent != null && isNfcActive) {
            processIntent(intent)
        }
    }
```